# After TYPO3 TV upgrade 1.3.7 to 1.7.0, FCE content element fields not displaying in backend

Tags: xml, data-structures, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I've upgraded TYPO3's extension TemplaVoilà from 1.3.7 to 1.7.0, all was ok. 
But now in my edit page module, all my FCEs with a field of eType "ce" (content element) won't display in the backend anymore.

I've remapped my FCE, checked the datastructure but nothing wrong.

Someone have an idea please ?

Here's my ce field's xml

```
<field_fce_text type="array">
    <tx_templavoila type="array">
        <title>Texte</title>
        <sample_data type="array">
            <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
        </sample_data>
        <eType>ce</eType>
        <preview>1</preview>
        <proc type="array">
            <int>0</int>
            <HSC>0</HSC>
            <stdWrap></stdWrap>
        </proc>
        <oldStyleColumnNumber>0</oldStyleColumnNumber>
        <enableDragDrop>1</enableDragDrop>
    </tx_templavoila>
    <TCEforms type="array">
        <config type="array">
            <type>group</type>
            <internal_type>db</internal_type>
            <allowed>tt_content</allowed>
            <size>5</size>
            <maxitems>200</maxitems>
            <minitems>0</minitems>
            <multiple>1</multiple>
            <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
        </config>
        <label>Texte</label>
    </TCEforms>
</field_fce_text>
```

Comment: Weird, check the non used elements if they are not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy... I had to remap all the FCEs